# Istio Ingress Regex Negation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I'm using Kubernetes with Istio which comes with traffic management. All backend api endpoints starts with `/api/**` followed by specific uri except frontend service. Frontend service has no any general uri prefix.

What i want to achieve is in the istio `VirtualService` use a regular expression that basically says, if a requested uri does not start with `/api/`, let it be served by frontend-service.

This is my `VirtualService`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-frontend-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
  {{ include "application.domain" . }}
  gateways:
  - iprocure-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: '^(?!\/api\/).*'
    route:
    - destination:  
        host: {{ printf "%s.%s.svc.cluster.local" .Values.frontendService.serviceName .Release.Name }}
        port:
          number: {{ .Values.frontendService.service.port }}
```

What is the `regex` value that I can use to make all request that does not start with `/api/` be served with frontend-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing the single quotes from the regex: field , from other [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14983) posts they are not being used.

[Virtual Service uses ECMAscript style](http://ecmascript%20regex) so when you add the single quotes it searches literally for the string between them

Answer (score 2):

See  [Istio 1.4.x upgrade notes](https://istio.io/news/releases/1.4.x/announcing-1.4/upgrade-notes/) under the heading "Regex engine changes".  Envoy has moved to the Google Re2 "safe" regex engine which doesn't support negative look-ahead. An opt-out via an environment variable to Pilot is possible but will be removed in future versions.  I've yet to find a long-term solution to this other than writing long regexs.

For your particular case try

```
regex: "^/((a$)|(ap$)|(api$)|([^a].*)|(a[^p].*)|(ap[^i].*)|(api[^/].*))"
```

Comment: What if I wanted to match all urls but the ones starting with 'api'?